# Thermodynamics equality question

Tags: thermodynamics

Can someone help with this question ? 
it's a thermodynamic question based upon Sonttage book 7th edition

(*)the question states :-

R-152a with a volume of 15 L and at 36 Celsius degrees with an equality of 80 % 
can some one help to find the mass of the substance .

and there is another thing i need help with, (*when it comes to thermodynamic questions which includes springs.

(*)What is the balance point of a spring in a spring - piston -cylinder system

appreciate your help guys

Comment: btw equality is not quality